# R recursive conditionals nested with two conditions

Tags: r, nested, conditional-statements

I´ve seen some questions similar but not yet solving this exactly. Hope not to be wrong.

I have a DF like that:

```
Invoices<-c(20171100247, 20171100408, 20171200376,20171201052, 21609000088)
Oustanding.days<-c(15,85,96,251,123)
Quantile.low<-c(25,21,22,23,24)
Quantile.Medium<-c(45,65,85,93,74)
Quantile.top<-c(74,89,101,175,125)
Remittances<-c(25,47,5,7,2)
df<-cbind(Invoices,Oustanding.days,Quantile.low,Quantile.Medium,Quantile.top,Remittances)
df
        Invoices Oustanding.days Quantile.low Quantile.Medium Quantile.top Remittances
[1,] 20171100247              15           25              45           74          25
[2,] 20171100408              85           21              65           89          47
[3,] 20171200376              96           22              85          101           5
[4,] 20171201052             251           23              93          175           7
[5,] 21609000088             123           24              74          125           2
```

I would like to create a column of ***"Payment accuracy"*** with conditionals, in that sense:

If remittances are below 5 then I would like to assign the accuracy lineally:

1) df$Outstanding.days <60 -> print "too early"

2) df$Outstanding.days >60 <90 -> print "early"

3) df$Outstanding.days >90 -> print "late"

If remittances are beyond 5 i would like to assign it with the quantiles:

1) df$Outstanding.days < Quantile.low -> print "too early"

2) df$Outstanding.days > Quantile.low & < Quantile.Medium -> print "early"

3) df$Outstanding.days > Quantile.Medium & < Quantile.top -> print "On date"

4) df$Outstanding.days > Quantile.top -> print "late"

I´m trying to use transform and the nested conditionals

```
df.final<-transform(df,Payment.accuracy=( 
if (df$OutStandingDays <= df$Quantile.low) {print 
("too early")}
else (print ("NA"))))
```

But I´m doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when` from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package to assign values based on multiple conditions. Nested ifelse statements or for-loop sometimes could be too complicated and difficult to read.

The last line `TRUE ~ NA_character_` is to specify `NA` to rows that do not meet any conditions above.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(`Payment accuracy` = case_when(
    Remittances < 5 & Outstanding.days < 60                            ~ "too early",
    Remittances < 5 & Outstanding.days >= 60 & Outstanding.days < 90   ~ "early",
    Remittances < 5 & Outstanding.days >= 90                           ~ "late",
    Remittances >= 5 & Outstanding.days < Quantile.low                 ~ "too early",
    Remittances >= 5 & Outstanding.days >= Quantile.low & 
      Outstanding.days < Quantile.Medium                               ~ "early",
    Remittances >= 5 & Outstanding.days >= Quantile.Medium & 
      Outstanding.days < Quantile.top                                  ~ "On date",
    Remittances >= 5 & Outstanding.days >= Quantile.top                ~ "late",
    TRUE                                                               ~ NA_character_
  ))
df2
#      Invoices Outstanding.days Quantile.low Quantile.Medium Quantile.top Remittances Payment accuracy
# 1 20171100247               15           25              45           74          25        too early
# 2 20171100408               85           21              65           89          47          On date
# 3 20171200376               96           22              85          101           5          On date
# 4 20171201052              251           23              93          175           7             late
# 5 21609000088              123           24              74          125           2             late
```

**DATA**

Please notice that you had typos in your original code, such as `Outstanding.days` and `Remittances`. In addition, you did not create a data frame by `cbind`. The function you need is `data.frame`. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is to make sure the column type is character, not factor.

```
Invoices<-c(20171100247, 20171100408, 20171200376,20171201052, 21609000088)
Outstanding.days<-c(15,85,96,251,123)
Quantile.low<-c(25,21,22,23,24)
Quantile.Medium<-c(45,65,85,93,74)
Quantile.top<-c(74,89,101,175,125)
Remittances<-c(25,47,5,7,2)
df <- data.frame(Invoices, Outstanding.days, Quantile.low, 
                 Quantile.Medium, Quantile.top, Remittances,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this solution I split the data considering the two conditions on `remittances` and then I collapse by rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

# First condition
df_less5 = df %>% filter(Remittances < 5)

df_less5 = df_less5 %>% 
  mutate(payment_accuracy = ifelse(Oustanding.days < 60, "too early",
                                   ifelse(Oustanding.days >60 & Oustanding.days <90, "early", "late")))

# Second condition
df_more5 = df %>% filter(Remittances > 5)

df_more5 = df_more5 %>% 
  mutate(payment_accuracy = ifelse(Oustanding.days < Quantile.low, "too early",
                                   ifelse(Oustanding.days > Quantile.low & Oustanding.days < Quantile.Medium, "early",
                                          ifelse(Oustanding.days > Quantile.Medium & Oustanding.days < Quantile.top, "on_date", 
                                                 ifelse(Oustanding.days > Quantile.top, "late", "other")))))


# new dataset
df_new = bind_rows(df_less5, df_more5)
```

Which gives this output:

```
 > df_new

  Invoices Oustanding.days Quantile.low Quantile.Medium Quantile.top Remittances payment_accuracy
1 21609000088             123           24              74          125           2             late
2 20171100247              15           25              45           74          25        too early
3 20171100408              85           21              65           89          47          on_date
4 20171201052             251           23              93          175           7             late
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a column correcting to df (if you want to extract that column it will be easy afterwards), where I used your last code lines:

```
 Invoices<-c(20171100247, 20171100408, 20171200376,20171201052, 21609000088)
 Oustanding_days<-c(15,85,96,251,123)
 Quantile_low<-c(25,21,22,23,24)
 Quantile_Medium<-c(45,65,85,93,74)
 Quantile_top<-c(74,89,101,175,125)
 Remittances<-c(25,47,5,7,2)
 df<-  cbind(Invoices,Oustanding_days,Quantile_low,Quantile_Medium,Quantile_top,Remittances)
 df <- as.data.frame(df)



 for (i in 1:length(df[,1])){
   if(df$Oustanding_days[i] <= df$Quantile_low[i]){
     df$final[i] <- print("too early")
   } else {
     df$final[i] <-print("NA")
   }
 }
```

With that example you should be able to reproduce all the conditions you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` and nested `ifelse`-statements for this.

Note that statements like `>Quantile.low & < Quantile.Medium` exclude the case where it is equal to one of those values, you should use `<=` for that. i.e. it should be either `>=Quantile.low & < Quantile.Medium` or `>Quantile.low & <= Quantile.Medium`. In the example below I have assumed the latter option.

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)   
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(x=ifelse(Remittances<5,
                     ifelse(Oustanding.days<=60,'too early',
                            ifelse(Oustanding.days>60 & Oustanding.days<=90,'early','late')),NA)) %>%
  mutate(x=ifelse(Remittances>=5,
                  ifelse(Oustanding.days<=Quantile.low,'too early',
                         ifelse(Oustanding.days>Quantile.low & Oustanding.days<=Quantile.Medium,'low',
                                ifelse(Oustanding.days>Quantile.Medium & Oustanding.days <= Quantile.top,'On date','late'))),x))
```

which returns:

```
     Invoices Oustanding.days Quantile.low Quantile.Medium Quantile.top Remittances         x
1 20171100247              15           25              45           74          25 too early
2 20171100408              85           21              65           89          47   On date
3 20171200376              96           22              85          101           5   On date
4 20171201052             251           23              93          175           7      late
5 21609000088             123           24              74          125           2      late
```

Hope this helps!